# How to stop an excel NOW() formula from refreshing

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel report I'm using that has multiple SQL tables inserted and therefore I have a command button that runs a macro that refreshes all the tables. I'm trying to add some code to that macro that will create a timestamp of the last time I refreshed the tables.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Range("I17").Formula = "=Now()"
End Sub
```

This does what I want but the issue is my report has a lot of other cells that constantly update the sheet, which in turn cause the timestamp cell (I17) to refresh constantly.

What can I do to make it so that the NOW() function will "lock" to that time and won't refresh unless I specifically click my macro button?

Comment: Make it fixed text? - `Range("I17").Value = Now()`

Comment: Seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexK. `Now` is a property getter of the `VBA.DateTime` module - the parentheses are misleadingly redundant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula re-evaluates its result every time it's re-calculated, *by definition*. If that wasn't the case, Excel would be useless.

What you want isn't a *formula* then, but a *value*.

So instead of using Excel's `NOW()` function, use VBA's `DateTime.Now` property to assign the cell's *value*:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I17").Value = VBA.DateTime.Now
```

With everything implicitly qualified it's as short as:

```
[I17] = Now
```

I encourage you to find a middle ground - implicit references are a terribly common source of bugs. Something like this seems acceptable, as long as you don't have a `Now` variable, constant, procedure, or module in scope that would *hide* the `VBA.DateTime` property:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I17") = Now
```

The above instruction explicitly qualifies the `Range` call with the active sheet, implicitly uses the `Range` object's *default property* (`Value`), and implicitly qualifies the `Now` property from the `VBA.DateTime` standard library module.

Comment: @Downvoter mind explaining what's wrong with this answer so I can improve it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never coded in VBA before and so I'm still learning the basics but this gave some good basic understanding.

Comment: I'll check it out on my personal computer! My work system won't allow any downloading of 3rd party extensions or add-ons unfortunately, which is where I'm using all my VBA coding.